# What is your level of external data?

Tags: data-format

I'm working on an internship of Big Data, I've build a predictive model. To enrich my model, I'm searching for the open data / external (paid) data. But I could only find the data that is in type of regional - zip code related data, there are no data that correspond specifically to each individual.

So my question is, do you have the same situation, or you are able to find an external data set perfectly coresponds to each observation in your data set?

Answer (score 1):

All data comes with the bias of their collection, so unless you collect you're own data and be careful at the bias you might introduce, they will rarely fit your exact purpose and you will need to rework them (clean, normalize, aggregate, consolidate) before using them.

To answer to your data request, it will be helpful if you can specify a domain. Are you looking for demographic, agricultural, weather or economic data?